# AWS S3 Pre Signed URL with Metadata

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-java-2.0

Here is the code snippet where I am trying to upload a document with some custom metadata using AWS S3 pre signed URL.

```
        try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createSystem()) {

        var tempFile = File.createTempFile(document.getName(), FilenameUtils.getExtension(document.getOriginalFilename()));
        document.transferTo(tempFile);

        var fileEntity = new FileEntity(tempFile);
        var httpPut = new HttpPut(url);
        // Here 403 httpPut.setHeader("x-amz-meta-title", "Test Title");
        httpPut.setEntity(fileEntity);
        var response = httpClient.execute(httpPut);
        log.info("HTTP response code {}", response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Oops! Error", e);
    }
```

Unfortunately setting a custom header as above throws 403. It works fine when I take out the header. Even works okay when you add an irrelevant metadata key say "abc" - Obviously not adding metadata, but returns 200 OK. The issue seems only when you specify "x-amz-meta-".

Any thoughts?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add metadata while using boto3 create\_presigned\_post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62961099/how-to-add-metadata-while-using-boto3-create-presigned-post)  The presign request must include the headers too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metadata of a presigned url are set, when you create it. They are prefilled and can't be modified by the client.

The only thing you can do is set an expected value and optionally a condition. In the condition you can specify to reject the upload, if the expected meta-data value isn't supplied.